# String separated from a comma Separated NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a string as
category=AC,Credit,Entertainment,Bars;
I want to separate this string from comma in ns array for example myarray=(AC,Credit,Entertainment,Bars)

```
    myCategory=[restaurantInfo objectForKey:@"specialCriteria"];

NSMutableArray *newArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


      [newArray3 addObject:[myCategory componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
NSLog(@"new array=%@",newArray3 );
```

My category is my NSString,restaurantInfo is my nsmutable dictionary which is retrieving value from user defaults.The code is only seperating first value only and the output is as

> new array=(
>           (
>           AC,
>           " Bar",
>           " Credit Card",
>           " Entertainment"
>   )
>   )

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
myCategory = restaurantInfo[@"specialCriteria"];

NSArray *newArray3 = [myCategory componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"new array = %@", newArray3);
```

Comment: The output is coming same.There is no change

Comment: It's different. With my code it will be `new array = [ AC, " Bar", " Credit Card", " Entertainment" ]`. What do you expect (or want) it to be?

Comment: Its done.I have used object at index for my array,its working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
myCategory=[restaurantInfo valueForKey:@"specialCriteria"];
NSArray *pathParts = [myCategory componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. 1) You needlessly alloc/init a mutable array that is never used. 2) You assign an `NSArray` to a variable with a type of `NSMutableArray`. That's not a good thing to do.